# How to broadcast information with Bluetooth on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'd like to know how to broadcast information with Bluetooth on Android.

I'm thinking to utilize the service name for SDP record in listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord() to broadcast the information. However, I couldn't find any method to use to read the service name for SDP record. May I know is there any way to read that?

Or is there any other more appropriate approaches to broadcast information with Bluetooth? Plz enlighten me if u know. Really need to know this fast for my project. Ur help would be greatly appreciated. =)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Android Bluetooth API doesn't provide a public method for getting the names of discovered services.  Nor does it provide a way to get the UUIDs of running services on a target device.  However, when developing my own application I found [this post](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2010/11/android-bluetooth-rfcomm/) which details the steps necessary to get access to hidden methods to provide the UUIDs.  Of course using private APIs is not supported, etc., etc., but I was able to get it to work in my app.  With that said, I decided against using the private APIs and rather just try and connect to my desired service (with my specific UUID), catching any errors in the connection attempt.

Comment: Thx a lot for ur answer. =)

1. Apparently, the hidden methods are only retrieving UUIDs, rather than name of the SDP record. How do u get the names of the services?

2. Btw, as I know, a service is only associated with only 1 UUID, but I see that the methods in ur post mentioned, is able to retrieve an array of ParcelUUIDs. Does this mean that a service can be associated with more than 1 UUID?

3. I'm not sure what is the use of getting the UUIDs, since if u can determine which UUID u're going to connect, doesn't it means u know the UUID beforehand?

Comment: You're right, I was confusing things a bit :-)  I'll update my answer.  But in response to your questions:  1) I wasn't able to find a way to do that in Android, which made me rework my entire Bluetooth protocol which was based on service names.  2)  No, what you are receiving in the ParcelUUIDs is a set of _all_ of the UUIDs for each service that is registered on the device you are examining; 3) Getting the UUID is useful if you only want to connect to a device that you are sure is running your desired service.  For my app this extra overhead wasn't necessary.

Comment: Okay, while waiting for your update, I'd like to know about a few things. Are you writing a new Bluetooth protocol for your app? Are you designing your app to broadcast information too? & if so, is writing a Bluetooth protocol is necessary to broadcast information? Which part in the Android API are u overriding?

Comment: Btw, do u think it's possible to connect to several devices at the same time with Bluetooth? If it is, do you've any idea how to implement it, in contrast to 1-to-1 connection?

Comment: I'm using Bluetooth RFCOMM sockets to send data bi-directionally.  My app consists of client and server threads on each device; the client searches for other devices running the software (by trying to connect to a pre-defined UUID) and then opens up a client RFCOMM socket to the other device.  The server just listens for incoming connections.  I'm using google protobuf library to format the data, which is simply a bytestream.  As far as I can tell (but I'm not entirely sure) multiple client connections are possible, as I spawn multiple threads and this does not seem to affect performance.